# Compute the value of the $30$th derivative of the function $g(x) = \sinh{\left(x^4\right)}$ at the origin, i.e. $g^{(30)}(0)$.

Tags: calculus

Compute the value of the $30$th derivative of the function $g(x) = \sinh{\left(x^4\right)}$ at the origin, i.e. $g^{(30)}(0)$.
So we have the (Macluarin) series
\begin{equation*}
\sinh{(x)} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}.
\end{equation*}
at $x = 0$ so
\begin{equation*}
\sinh{(x^4)} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(x^4)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{8n+4}}{(2n+1)!}.
\end{equation*}
The Maclaurin series for $\sinh{(x^4)}$ is
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(x^4)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{8n+4}}{(2n+1)!} = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^m}{\left(\frac{m}{4}\right)!}.
\end{equation*}
We can see that the coefficient for $x^m$ is $\frac{1}{\left(\frac{m}{4}\right)!}$. On the other hand, this is the Maclaurin series for $g(x)$, and so the coefficient on $x^m$ is equal to $\frac{g^{(m)}(0)}{m}$. Equating these two, we have
\begin{equation*}
\frac{g^{(m)}(0)}{m} = \frac{1}{\left(\frac{m}{4}\right)!} \Longleftrightarrow g^{(m)}(0) = \frac{m}{\left(\frac{m}{4}\right)!}.
\end{equation*}
Substituting $m = 30$ gives $g^{(30)}(0) = \frac{30}{7.5!}$. Am I on the right track here?

Comment: You're on the right track; now consider what the 30th derivative of a term in your series, evaluated at the origin, would yield if (i) $8n+4 \lt 30$ and (ii) $8n+4 \gt 30.$

Comment: You don't need the $30^{th}$ term. You need a term with $x^{30}$.

Comment: The MacLaurin series only has terms for $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geqslant 0}$; you cannot simply use the change of variable $m=8n+4$ and assume this will hold for all $m \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geqslant 0},$ e.g. if $m=3,$ then $n=\frac{-1}{8},$ which cannot be. Please consider my earlier comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second formula
$$g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty{x^{8n+4}\over(2n+1)!}$$
is still correct. Now the $m^{\rm th}$ derivative of any power series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^k$ at $0$ is equal to the coefficient $a_m$ belonging to $x^m$, times a combinatorial factor. In your case $m=30$. Since $8n+4\ne30$ for all $n\geq0$ it follows that $a_{30}=0$, hence $g^{(30)}(0)=0$.

Comment: Great thank you.

Comment: What if say I wanted to calculate the $19$-th, $20$-th and $21$-st order Maclaurin polynomial for $f(x) = x\left(1-\cos{(2x^3)}\right)$?

Comment: @squenshl: Ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely on the right track. Last thing you need to know is that the coefficient of $x^n$ in the Maclaurin series is given by $a_n=\frac{f^{n}(0)}{n!}$

Comment: What do you mean coefficient of $x^n$?

Comment: Never mind I got it... It’s $\frac{1}{61!}$!!!

Comment: @squenshl You got it wrong.

Comment: More specifically, look at your series. What is the coefficient of $x^{30}$? You might think "Wait, there is no $x^{30}$!". You would be correct. Thus, what is the coefficient of $x^{30}$? Once you understand this, you're done.